# Proxmox vps container connection problems

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, openvz, proxmox

I have Proxmox on my node server which have ip:5.189.190.* 
and I created openvz container on an ip : 213.136.87.* and installed centos 6 on it

The problem:
Cann't connect to container ssh directly
Can't open apache server centos welcome page
When I enter container from the node can't ping any sites or wget any url but I can connect 127.0.0.1 and the main node ip

My Configuration:
container /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

container  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-venet0

```
DEVICE=venet0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=213.136.87.*
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
BROADCAST=213.136.87.*
IPV6INIT="yes"
```

container  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-venet0

```
DEVICE=venet0:0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=213.136.87.*
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

node /etc/network/interfaces

```
# network interface settings
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  5.189.190.*
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        gateway  5.189.190.*
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

node /etc/resolv.conf
having DC nameservers correctly

container ping result:

```
# ping google.com -c 3
ping: unknown host google.com
```

container traceroute result:

```
# traceroute google.com
google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `google.com' on position 1 (argc 1)
```

node ping result:

```
# ping google.com -c 3
PING google.com (74.125.29.139) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from qg-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.29.139): icmp_req=1 ttl=41 time=110 ms
64 bytes from qg-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.29.139): icmp_req=2 ttl=41 time=110 ms
64 bytes from qg-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.29.139): icmp_req=3 ttl=41 time=110 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 110.450/110.462/110.474/0.383 ms
```

node traceroute result:

```
# traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (74.125.29.139), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  ip-1-90-136-213.static.contabo.net (213.136.90.1)  0.506 ms  0.517 ms  0.513 ms
 2  ffm-b11-link.telia.net (62.115.36.237)  0.493 ms  0.491 ms  0.484 ms
 3  hbg-b1-link.telia.net (62.115.139.164)  15.379 ms  15.393 ms  15.384 ms
 4  hbg-bb4-link.telia.net (213.155.135.88)  16.048 ms hbg-bb4-link.telia.net (213.155.135.86)  15.419 ms hbg-bb4-link.telia.net (213.155.135.84)  15.456 ms
 5  nyk-bb1-link.telia.net (80.91.247.127)  96.568 ms nyk-bb2-link.telia.net (80.91.247.123)  107.638 ms nyk-bb1-link.telia.net (80.91.247.129)  96.582 ms
 6  nyk-b6-link.telia.net (213.155.130.251)  105.478 ms  105.470 ms nyk-b6-link.telia.net (80.91.254.32)  101.005 ms
 7  google-ic-303645-nyk-b6.c.telia.net (213.248.78.250)  101.235 ms  105.746 ms  105.719 ms
 8  209.85.248.242 (209.85.248.242)  101.694 ms  106.213 ms  106.250 ms
 9  209.85.249.212 (209.85.249.212)  101.225 ms 209.85.246.4 (209.85.246.4)  101.597 ms 209.85.252.242 (209.85.252.242)  101.179 ms
10  209.85.249.11 (209.85.249.11)  102.247 ms  112.917 ms 72.14.239.93 (72.14.239.93)  97.931 ms
11  64.233.174.9 (64.233.174.9)  104.733 ms 66.249.95.229 (66.249.95.229)  109.232 ms 66.249.95.231 (66.249.95.231)  106.086 ms
12  72.14.234.53 (72.14.234.53)  106.179 ms 72.14.238.73 (72.14.238.73)  110.471 ms 72.14.234.53 (72.14.234.53)  106.170 ms
13  * * *
14  qg-in-f139.1e100.net (74.125.29.139)  110.479 ms  110.656 ms  106.154 ms
```

Any ideas will be welcomed

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
On node add static routing for container IP address. Edit /etc/network/interfaces and add for vmbr0 interface:

```
post-up route add -host $containerIP gw $nodeIP
pre-down route del -host $containerIP gw $nodeIP
```

On container, add following line to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-venet0

```
GATEWAY=$nodeIP
SCOPE="peer $nodeIP"
```

Also create file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-venet0 with content:

```
0.0.0.0/0 via $nodeIP
```

Restart network on node and on container, check if it works.

I use above configuration for several of my KVM hosts and VMs where IP on the VM is in different subnet than IP of the node.

Comment: netmask 255.255.255.255 or netmask 255.255.255.0 ?

Comment: My bad, 'network' statement shouldn't be there as you are adding static route for single host. I've just edited my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help.
but it doesn't work with error
Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not re-enable some interfaces ... (warning).
Reconfiguring network interfaces...
Waiting for vmbr0 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 2 seconds).
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
vzifup-post ERROR: Unable to add route ip route add 213.136.87.221 dev venet0
run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/vzifup-post exited with return code 34
On restart network on node

Comment: in few words, your containers has public ips and your nodes private address?